# FileLoadException .net core docker application

Tags: c#, linux, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

What is the easiest way to find the reason for a `FileLoadException:` in docker, when everything is running on local windows and linux machine?

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
File name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.AddLogging(IServiceCollection services, Action`1 configure)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.AddLogging(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at Simplic.Cloud.WorkerService.BaseProgram.Main(String[] args, Action`1 setup, Action`1 configureHostBuilder)
```

**EDIT**

I could reproduce the problem on ubuntu as well. This question will be updated with information from: [Wrong assembly version in output when compiling under linux (.net core)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64727025/wrong-assembly-version-in-output-when-compiling-under-linux-net-core)

Comment: By ensuring that restore of packages and build was successful and `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` file is present

Comment: When calling `RUN ls -R` the files are in the docker-image.

Comment: Pls share you `Dockerfile`. As long as you are moving the entire code base inside docker image and compiling the code using the sdk version of .NET Core. You should not be seeing this error. If it were to fail it'll fail while building the image. 

Easy ask.. are you moving the built project inside docker using `COPY` command or are you moving the code and building the image?

Comment: @ZiaullahKhan the problem occurs in any linux distribution, I've opened a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64727025/wrong-assembly-version-in-output-when-compiling-under-linux-net-core that decribes the problem in more details. I think I will close this question. Maybe you can take a look here as well. Thank you very much so far!