# Wrong assembly version in output when compiling under linux (.net core)

Tags: .net-core

I recognized a different compiler behaviour under .net core 3.1 for windows and linux. The problem is, that under **linux** and **windows** different assembly versions of a dependency is moved to the output directory when compiling. Having the following project structure:

```
My.Net.App
  > Reference: Sample.dll (Version 1.3.5)
    > Reference: Newtonsoft.Json (Version 11.0.2)
  > Reference: AnotherSample.dll (Version 4.2.1)
    > Reference: Newtonsoft.Json (Version 12.0.3)
```

As you can see, my project is referencing `Sample`-package and `AnotherSample`-package. Both of these packages are referencing `Newtonsoft.Json` in different versions. When I compile my project under **windows**, the output directory contains `Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3`. When I'm compiling the same code under **linux**, the output directory contains `Newtonsft.Json 11.0.2` and my application stops working.

I've tried using assembly binding and referencing `Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3` directly in `My.Net.App`.

**EDIT**

I've got the same issue when compiling under a local `ubuntu`, in `azure DevOps` and under docker.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: When you say "compiling under linux", you mean running `dotnet build`? Also, you'll have much better responses on the dotnet github repository than here (it might be an actual bug)

Comment: Are you doing a clean build?  The intermediate object file may have older version and when you updated Net the objects dependencies did not force them to get rebuilt.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yes sorry, I mean `dotnet build`.

Comment: @jdweng yes, I run the build on Azure DevOps pipelines.

Comment: And why didn't you mention absolutely anywhere that the compilation is being done in a ADO pipeline? Rather than adding strange details, just look at the ouput of the pipeline and add the relevant parts

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto because I've got the same result when making a clean build on my local ubuntu machine. But I will add some more information I can find.

Comment: How did you install last version on Linux machine?  If you built on windows with new version of dll than you have to also put latest version of linux.